# First time error in Azure Log analytics or application insights

Tags: azure-application-insights

How can we find the first time error in Log Analytics or Application insights. There could be errors that get repeatedly written to log files. But I want to find errors that are not in this error pattern and send an alert when it happens.

Or search these 'different'/irregular errors (not necessarily first time) during a particular hour or custom time.

I am thinking of the following options as solutions(existing or common errors can ran up to 100-500 lines):

1. running a saved kusto query with a list of hardcoded error messages(resulting mismatches can be listed as new errors).
2. Create a Data Table with all existing/common errors (in Kusto but will it stay stored?) and do the same as above(join)
3. Or use logic apps and store the known errors in table storage.
       retrieve the table storage first and run the join query against log
       analytics.

Has anyone done this before and what would you suggest the best option is?

Answer (score 0):

Possible options can be

- If the known errors list is small , you can adjust your Kusto query on Log 
  Analytics/Application Insights to exclude those common errors and create an alert 
  based on your alert logic (custom query, number of results, threshold, period (grain) 
  and frequency)
- If you want to maintain the errors list with in Log Analytics/Application Insights as 
  a custom events , you very well can call the respective API's and ingest the data. 
  Some documentation reference for the [same](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-collector-api).
  Once you have your list of errors as custom logs/events you can write your Kusto query 
  accordingly.

Additional Documentation Reference for dynamic thresholds and smart detections, see if this fits your requirement.

[Metric Alerts with Dynamic Thresholds in Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-dynamic-thresholds)

[Smart Detection in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/proactive-diagnostics)

Hope the above information helps !